# Why can't the title be formatted?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, code-formatting

I am just wondering why it is not possible to format the title - at least the code formatting would be useful sometimes.

Comment: So per your tags, this is a feature-request to add code formatting to the titles?

Comment: @AlBundy On Meta, especially on feature requests, voting may indicate (dis)agreement rather than post quality.

Comment: Al Bundy, if you tagged your question as [discussion], and then asked for possible pros and cons of introducing markdown to titles, it might not have gotten so many downvotes. (BTW, don't change the tags now, since this case is pretty much closed)

Comment: I find this interesting to put HTML tags as `<span>` or to hightlight some technical name. If highlightinh is not possible, I write 'span' but it is less readable.

Answer (score 13):

The title of a question should describe the question - a short descriptive text.

Adding markup and code capabilities to it would just make things messy and some people would abuse these features.

It is not a feature that would add so much value that it would be worth the complexity both in the handling code and in having user interactions work well (a formatting bar for the title, help sections on how to format titles correctly etc...).

Comment: Given our experience with MathJax in titles, I agree the extra complexity is probably not worth the benefit. But [I still wish](https://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/forums/1722-general/suggestions/19339-markdown-doesn-t-get-get-translated-in-question-ti) Markdown worked in every text box  on the site.